# Clicking element by index, multiple elements with same identifier

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumberjs

So I have this identifier..

```
var dropDownMenus = $('.select2-choice.ui-select-match.ng-scope');
```

And there are two of them. If I just do a dropDownMenus.click(); it will work because it defaults to the first one. but whenever I do a dropDownMenus[0].click(), I get a click undefined error. What is the easiest way to click a particular index?

Answer (score 2):

Use `$$` instead of `$` to find multiple elements:

```
var dropDownMenus = $$('.select2-choice.ui-select-match.ng-scope');
```

Then, to click the first element:

```
dropDownMenus.first().click();
```

Or, the last:

```
dropDownMenus.last().click();
```

Or, the n-th:

```
dropDownMenus.get(n).click();
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks!